# Drawing a third variable curve on a 2 variable scatter plot in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to plot a curve (from Properties --> Lines and Curves) of Variable Z on a scatter plot of Variable X vs. Variable Y, in Spotfire.  Is it possible to do this? I thought it would be "curve from data table" (Var X and Y are imported columns and Var Z is a calculated column) but it does not seem to be working.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62DPZ.png)

Comment: What is the Z in relation to X and Y?

Comment: @scsimon,  Z = (0.3*SQRT(X/Y))

Comment: I think it's drawing it, it just can'd render on that scale since Z equals values so close to 1, at least with my small test data. Did you try and just enter the equation in the expression box?